# What is wrong with this truth table?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I started by making a truth table for A and B, with

$\begin{array}{c:c|c}A&B&A \wedge B\\\hline
T&T& T\\
T&F& F\\
F&T& F\\
F&F& F\end{array}$

To see what would happen, I made a table for ~A and ~B:

$\begin{array}{c:c|c}\neg A&\neg B&\neg A \wedge\neg B\\\hline
F&F& T\\
F&T& F\\
T&F& F\\
T&T& F\end{array}$

I am confident this is wrong, it doesn't make sense that the union of two statements is equal to the union of the opposite of those statements, but as far as I know, it also does make sense that the output for the first line is true if I say "neither statement A nor statement B is true" as it satisfies the condition of the union of the negation of the original statements.

Why is the table wrong? Why doesn't the union of those negations equal the preceding table?

Comment: For $A \land B$ the third line must be : F-T.

Comment: For the second formula, the case T-T must result into T.

Comment: But T-T means..."Yes the original statement A is true and yes the other original statement B is true" so how does that qualify as the union of negations? Because the statement is that "Not A as well as Not B is true", so if "A and B"  is true then that seems like a contradiction.

Comment: Your third column must be the AND of the first two columns. So if the first two columns have $F$ and $F$ in the first row, the corresponding third column's entry must be $F \land F = F$.

Comment: You have to decide if you are reding the column $\lnot A \land \lnot B$ against the columns $A \mid B$ or against $\lnot A \mid \lnot B$.

Comment: In the first case, the fourth row is $A$ is F and $B$ is F and thus $\lnot A \land \lnot B$ is $T \land T$ i.e. T. In the second case the fourth row is $\lnot A$ is T and $\lnot B$ is T and thus $\lnot A \land \lnot B$ is again $T \land T$ i.e. T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equal.  Note that the second table is upside down (relative to the first).

Put them together and you get:

$$\begin{array}{c:c|c:c|c:c} A & B&\neg A& \neg B& A\land B& \neg A\land\neg B\\\hline T & T &F&F& T & F\\ T & F&F&T & F & F\\F & T&T&F& F& F\\F & F& T&T&F & T\end{array}$$

Comment: If I make a table for ~A as the first column, and ~B as the second column, then don't I arrive at the first two columns of the second table in the OP? Why not? I made the third column based on those two columns, and I see no reason why I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: Upside down is upside down.

Comment: I guess that would explain tables. Why isn't it right to derive the results from the 3rd and 4th column in your table? What is the generalized fallacy in that? I do not understand why that won't work.

Comment: $\neg (A \wedge B) \neq (\neg A \wedge \neg B).$

Comment: Right I've already known that since the OP, what I am asking is why the method  I used in the table doesn't work even though it seems it should logically follow.

Comment: If not-A is false, and not-B is false, why would you say not-A-and-not-B is true? false-and-false is false.